# Can I disable bootstrap carausel which is in background for one of the 4 tabs in angular project?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've single page tab based angular website with bootstrap carausel in the background.

In that there is a separate component for the background and have a `<app-background></app-background>` in `app.html` to make it work.

This works perfect for all 4 tabs of my website, but I want to disable this background carausel one one tab out of 4 tabs.

I tried restructuring code where I inserted `<app-background></app-background>` only in required tabs but it didn't seem to have worked.

So in a nutshell, is there a way that I can disable the background carausel for only one tab?

Any help is appreciated.

Apologies that I couldn't paste the code snippet as there are different bits of components and pasting everything would not be good idea.

Comment: Are you using different `Routes` for the tabs?

Comment: No. All tabs are present in `navbar` component

Comment: Do you set any `variable` to a specific value when you switch tabs?

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly, it's a scrolling navbar similar to 
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy&stacked=h

and reg setting variable, I do change a class of tab to highlight respective tab based on which tab is selected or which is in the viewport when we scroll.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe you could use `*ngIf` on `app-background`, but `angular` would need to know which tab is the currently active one in order to exclude it using `*ngIf`.

Comment: whichever tab is selected will have a a class named `active` but this lies in `navbar` component and I have selector inserted in app (root) component for the component `background`. So this seems tricky for me.

Other way which I thought was to remove `background-carousel` class in background component when that tab is selected and add back when other tabs are selected but I kind of not able to think how i would do that across the components.

Comment: Use `@Input()` and `@Output()` to communicate between `Components`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a work around with jQuery. I put this script in index.html

```
<script>
 jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
        var position = jQuery(this).scrollTop() + 20;

        jQuery('.section').each(function() {
            var target = jQuery(this).offset().top;

            var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

            jQuery('ul > li > a[data-id=' + id + ']').removeClass('active');

            if (position >= target) {


                if(id != "gallery"){
                    jQuery('#myCarousel').addClass('background-carousel');
                } else {
                    jQuery('#myCarousel').removeClass('background-carousel');
                }

                jQuery('ul > li > a[data-id=' + id + ']').addClass('active');
                jQuery( 'a.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
            }
        });

});
</script>
```

This worked for me but because of this screen started flickering. 
Now I've decided different design for my website hence for now, I'm closing this issue as it worked partially.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, since you didn't post any code, my answer will have some assumptions.

In you `<app-background>` component, add an `ngIf` condition and bind it to some variable e.g.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" *ngIf="isCarouselHidden">
```

Create a data sharing service for emitting an event:

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataSharingService
{ 
    public OnCarouselShowHide = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    public carouselShowHide (isHidden: boolean): void {
        this.OnCarouselShowHide.next(isHidden);
    }
}
```

.. and subscribe to the event in your `<app-background>` component in your in ngOnInit:

```
constructor(private readonly dataSharingService: DataSharingService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSharingService.OnCarouselShowHide.subscribe(value =>
        {
            this.isCarouselHidden= value;
        });
}
```

Now, in your `navbar` component, when you click on the tabs, call the `carouselShowHide` method to show or hide carousel.

---

The other possibility is to use `@Input` & `@Output` to communicate between components ([Documentation Here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)) as `@Arg0n` mentioned in the comments. I have not worked with that so cant write an example. I am using the first approach in my project.